# How to see if a String Indifferent to uppercase or lowercase appears?

Tags: java

I want to get the index in a text where a word appears, but sometimes it could be uppercase or lowercase. I have this:

```
int startIndex = statement.indexOf("(title ''");
```

but "title ''" sometimes appears like "TITLE ''" or "Title''" and it could be like not recognized.

is there a way to ignore if it is upper or lowercase?

Comment: Removed groovy tag, as this seems to be Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try converting the string to lowercase first [`String#toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29):

```
int startIndex = statement.toLowerCase().indexOf("(title ''");
```

Comment: We will get the same result , even with uppercase